# Show that for any monic polynomial of degree $n$, the inner product $\langle q,q \rangle \geq \langle p_n,p_n\rangle$

Tags: polynomials, computational-mathematics, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $\{ p_n \}$ be a family of monic orthogonal polynomials associated with a inner product $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_a^b w(x)f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$. Show that for any monic polynomial of defree $n$, we have that $\langle q,q\rangle \geq \langle p_n,p_n\rangle$.

I feel like it should be an application of some well-known inequalities. I've tried to use Cauchy-Schwarz but haven't got anything.

Any hints or comments are welcome!
Thank you.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>`. Then you don't have to manually monkey with the spacing.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Edits made.

Comment: consider $q-p_n=q_1$ this is degree (at most) $n-1$ and then can be written as $a_{n-1}p_{n-1}+q_2$ of degree at most $n-2$ and you can continue; but now by orthogonality one gets that $\langle p_n,q_1 \rangle =0$ so $\langle q,q \rangle =\langle p_n,p_n\rangle+\langle q_1,q_1\rangle$ etc